# Using select in haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, haml

I currently have this select block

```
= f.label :item
= f.select(:item, ["Select"] + List.items(foo), {}, { :class => "form-control input", :id => "column" })
```

I need is to set the default option to any string I want, but I can't seem to figure out where to put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `include_blank:` option to set a default prompt. For example:

```
= f.select(:title, Book.all, include_blank: "Anything!")
```

Would render a select tag with a default value of "Anything". So for your case, I believe it would be:

```
= f.select(:item, ["Select"] + List.items(foo), {}, { :class => "form-control input", :id => "column", include_blank: 'Any string' })
```

Comment: This gave me a `ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 5, expected 1..4))`

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the `include_blank` option from the APIdock?

```
= f.label :item
= f.select(:item, List.items(foo), {include_blank: 'String'}, {html_options})
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select